# Elasticsearch CouchDB River no hit

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb

I have a problem with CouchDB and Elasticsearch. i use Docker to realise it. i have a working couchdb container on the default port. Now i use this container:

registry.hub.docker.com/u/jeko/elasticsearch-river-couchdb/

And i insert a new couchdb connection with this:
curl -X PUT '127.0.0.1:9200/_river/testdb/_meta' -d ' { "type" : "couchdb", "couchdb" : { "host" : "couchdb", "port" : 5984, "db" : "articles", "filter" : null }, "index" : { "index" : "articles", "type" : "articles", "bulk_size" : "100", "bulk_timeout" : "10ms" } }'

to have a working elasticsearch with the couchdb river. Now i checked with curl host/articles/articles/_search?pretty=true the documents. The Hits are empty.

```
{
 {
 "took" : 2,
 "timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
 "total" : 5,
 "successful" : 5,
 "failed" : 0
 },
 "hits" : {
 "total" : 0,
 "max_score" : null,
 "hits" : [ ]
 }
}
```

i turned the debugger on and checked the logging file. The output is this: http://pastebin.com/ETkNmJzT

The only conspicuous thing i found is this line: [2015-02-20 14:04:24,554][DEBUG][plugins                  ] [Arc] [/elasticsearch/plugins/river-couchdb/_site] directory does not exist.

But i doesn't understand why it doesn't work. i can curl the IP

Comment: Please if you found a solution, please share it.